# Eliminating an eigenvalue from the Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

I have a momentum space Hamiltonian $H(\vec k)$ for a Kagome lattice and I want to find its eigenvalues which may be dependent on $\vec k$. Now, I'm told that one of the eigenvalues for such Hamiltonians is "flat" (it has no $\vec k$-dependence). Obtaining the analytical form of the eigenvalues is difficult since the Hamiltonian is quite complex. I was told that one can do this easily by eliminating the flat eigenvalue and the resultant Hamiltonian is easy to work with. I want to know how this is done.

I think [this](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1209/0295-5075/95/20003) paper does the same thing (see right-column on page 2), however I don't fully understand this. Following the paper, I was able to get the non-flat energy bands, but didn't quite understand what I  was doing. Is there a name for this technique? Can anybody provide some links on it?

**Edit 1**: Here's the arXiv link of the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3792 . The relevant portion is on the second page.

**Edit 2**: I thought this was a common thing to do while calculating for energy bands, but following @ZeroTheHero's advice, here's what I am doing:

I have an electrical circuit in the form of Kagome lattice. This circuit shows topological behaviour. By using KCL and applying Fourier transform we can get the circuit's Laplacian $J$ defined as
$$I=JV$$
From this, we can get the Hamiltonian for this lattice-circuit (in momentum space):
\begin{align*}
H &= -iJ\\ &= \begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{\omega L}+2\omega(C_A+C_B) && -\omega C_A -\omega C_B e^{-i (\frac{k_xd}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}k_yd}{2})} && -\omega C_A -\omega C_B e^{-i k_xd}\\
-\omega C_A -\omega C_B e^{i (\frac{k_xd}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}k_yd}{2})} && -\frac{1}{\omega L}+2\omega(C_A+C_B) && -\omega C_A -\omega C_B e^{-i (\frac{k_xd}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}k_yd}{2})}\\
-\omega C_A -\omega C_B e^{i k_xd} && -\omega C_A -\omega C_B e^{i (\frac{k_xd}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}k_yd}{2})} && -\frac{1}{\omega L}+2\omega(C_A+C_B)\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Here, $\omega$ is the frequency of AC current, $C_A$ and $C_B$ are capacitances of the capacitors used in the circuit, $L$ is the inductance and $d$ is the lattice parameter.

Now let's define
$$
\psi_A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\text{,}  \quad
\psi_B = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{bmatrix}e^{iP} \\ e^{iQ} \\ e^{iR}\end{bmatrix}\text{,} \quad 
\psi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{bmatrix}\psi_A && \psi_B\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{bmatrix}1 && e^{iP} \\ 1 && e^{iQ} \\ 1 && e^{iR}\end{bmatrix}\text{,} \quad
D = 3\begin{bmatrix}-\omega C_A && 0\\
0 && -\omega C_B\end{bmatrix}\text{and}\quad
h = \psi D \psi^\dagger
$$

We can equate $H$ to $h$ (upto a constant times identity matrix), and get the appropriate values of $P$, $Q$ and $R$. Here, $P=0$, $Q = \frac{k_xd}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}k_yd}{2}$ and $R = k_xd$

We'll see that
$$
H = h+\left(3\omega(C_A+C_B)-\frac{1}{\omega L}\right)I_{3\times 3}
$$

We can ignore the 2nd term (containing the identity matrix) as that changes the eigenvalues only by a constant and does not change the eigenvectors and work only with $h$. Let $O = \psi^\dagger\psi$.

The wave function for non-ﬂat energy bands is given as linear combination of $\psi_A$ and $\psi_B$ ($\phi_A$ and $\phi_B$ are scalars)
$$
\gamma = \phi_A\psi_A+\phi_B\psi_B=\psi\phi \qquad \text{where }
\phi=\begin{bmatrix}\phi_A\\ \phi_B\end{bmatrix}
$$
Writing the Schrodinger equation
$$
h\gamma=E\gamma \Rightarrow \psi D \psi^\dagger \, \psi \phi = E\psi\phi \Rightarrow ODO\phi=EO\phi
$$
Multiplying by ($O^{1/2})^{-1}$, we get
$$
h_\psi \phi^\prime = E\phi^\prime
$$
where $h_\psi = O^{1/2}DO^{1/2}$ and $\phi^\prime = O^{1/2}\phi$

$h_\psi$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix and its eigenvalues can be given by
$$
\lambda_\pm = \frac{1}{2}\left(\text{tr}(h_\psi)\pm\sqrt{\text{tr}^2(h_\psi)-4\text{ det}(h_\psi)}\right)
$$
We can easily calculate det($h_\psi$) and tr($h_\psi$) and get the non-flat energy bands. Also, $h_\psi \phi^\prime = E\phi^\prime$ can be easily solved for eigenvectors.

So, my questions specific to this calculations are:

1. When we write $h = \psi D \psi^\dagger$, how does this eliminates the flat band?
2. Is there something special about $\psi_A$ and $\psi_B$ that's enabling us to eliminate the flat band?
3. Why is the eigenvector of $h$ (i.e., $\gamma$) a linear combination of $\psi_A$ and $\psi_B$?

Comment: The paper is behind a paywall. Is there an ArXiv link?

Comment: @mikestone please check the  edit

Comment: This is an interesting question but it requires additional details on your part as people are unlikely to plot through an arXiv submission to know what you’re talking about.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I've added my calculations in the edit, hope this helps.